# Add Landscape View (XCode)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, landscape-portrait

I'm working on a web browser app, and simply enough, I use arrows as the interface for home, back, forward, etc.

What I need is instructions on how to program landscape view in so that the buttons will be where I want them in landscape view, the same arrangement I use in portrait view.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the autoresizingmasks to allow the views to move on rotation.

[image: AutoResizingMasks]

Apple's [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW15) has all the details complete with illustrations and examples.

You'll also need to enable autorotation by adding this to the `UIViewController`s:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 return YES;
}
```

Comment: I have the boolean set, and have for awhile. Is there any way to see a simple example of say, the behavior of a square and keeping it in the top right corner after rotation? I'm a visual learner, and that's why I need to see this. Thanks!

Comment: @Jakexx360 I gave you a picture. It doesn't get more visual than that. Play around with the autoresizing masks and see what happens. You can do this programmatically or in the IB.

Comment: What I meant was, seeing an example of the syntax of the code helps greatly. i'm not asking for the answer, just a small example to help out.